# Prefilter queries in django for a session

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Currently, I have a unique UUID tied to all models, including a one-to-one relation with the user model. For filtering data based on this UUID, I save the UUID as a session variable for the logged-in user, and then in the views,

```
data = Model.objects.filter(unique_num=request.session.get('unique_num'))
```

Is it possible to prefilter these queries? For example, if the user logs in, I should just be able to

```
data = Model.objects.filter()
```

and it should show only related data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot write a [manage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/) for that purpose, because managers are loaded during class initialization, and know nothing about the current request, your best option is to write a `@classmethod` on your model.

```py
class Model(models.Model):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def unique(cls, unique_num):
        return cls.objects.filter(unique_num=unique_num)
```

And use it like this in the view layer:

```
qs = Model.unique(request.session.get("unique_num")).filter(...)
```

Comment: If you can write a classmethod for a model, you can also write a method for the manager, both are oblivious to a request, but can accept arbitrary arguments in methods like you do above. The upside to making it a queryset/manager method, is that it can be chained with other methods and sticks with the pattern.

Comment: This is a one kind of solution. I guess, the only way to make filters work is to implement RLS in the database and have middleware set they RLS for that session.